# Is there an equivalent of "onlyenv" that reserves the space for hidden content?

Tags: beamer, overlays

My code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

% Slide 1
\begin{onlyenv}<1->
\begin{verbatim}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}

% Slide 1 + Slide 2
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{verbatim}
$ cc hello.c
\end{verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}

% Slide 1 + Slide 3
\begin{onlyenv}<3>
\begin{verbatim}
$ cc hello.c
$ ./a.out
\end{verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}

% Slide 1 + Slide 4
\begin{onlyenv}<4>
\begin{verbatim}
$ cc hello.c
$ ./a.out
hello, world
\end{verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem with this code is that as the code is revealed, the content keeps jumping around due to changing height of the content. Is there an environment equivalent to `onlyenv` that would reserve the space for the content to be revealed in future slides.

I guess what I am asking is: The `\only` command does not reserve space for hidden content and it has an equivalent environment named `\onlyenv`. On the other hand, `\onslide` reserves space for hidden content and I am trying to find an equivalent environment for it.

Comment: Just replace `\begin{frame}[fragile]` by `\begin{frame}[fragile,t]` to avoid the jumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this with the `overprint` environment. Within this environment, the `\onslide` command functions as an `\item`.

I quote the beamer manual *(9.6.1 Making Commands and Environments Overlay Specification-Aware)*

> `\begin{overprint}[area width] 
>   environment contents 
>   \end{overprint}`
>
> The area width defaults to the text width. Inside the environment, use
>   **\onslide** commands to specify different things that should be shown for
>   this environment on different slides. The **\onslide** commands are used
>   like **\item** commands. Everything within the environment will be placed
>   in a rectangular area of the specified width. The height and depth of
>   the area are chosen large enough to accommodate the largest contents
>   of the area. The overlay specifications of the **\onslide** commands must
>   be disjoint. This may bea problem for handouts, since, there, all
>   overlay specifications default to **1**. If you use the option **handout**,
>   you can disable all but one **\onslide** by setting the others to **0**.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

% Slide 1
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1->
\begin{verbatim}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{verbatim}
\end{overprint}

% Slide 1 + Slide 2
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<2->
\begin{verbatim}

$ cc hello.c
\end{verbatim}
\end{overprint}

% Slide 1 + Slide 3
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<3->
\begin{verbatim}
$ ./a.out
\end{verbatim}
\end{overprint}

% Slide 1 + Slide 4
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<4->
\begin{verbatim}
hello, world
\end{verbatim}
\end{overprint}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The vertical space seems to have disappeared between the C code snippet and the shell snippet. Do you know anyway to preserve that?

Comment: Just add an empty line. I just updated the answer.